# Experience - consists of or includes

Tags: collocations

I'm preparing a resume and wonder what is correct?
**My experience ...
1) consists of ...
2) includes ...**
two years of digging holes and 1 year of filling them up [that line is just a silly example of some activity].

Answer (score 1):

Either could be OK. "Consists of" implies that the resume is a complete list of your total experience, while "includes" implies that this is a selected list.  A person seeking an entry level or junior position would probably be giving a complete list, and use "consists of", while a person with 30 years of experience in 20 different jobs will probably give the most recent ones and highlights of the earlier ones, and so might well use "includes"

Many resumes take the form of a bulleted list with just a heading of "experience" and specific job or volunteer positions. In that form there would be no such statement in the resume at all, so how to word it is not an issue.